# REPLACE empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I discover some behavior I didn't know before. Why this line of code does not work?

```
SELECT REPLACE('','','0') ==> returns ''
```

I can't even have `''` in where condition. It just doesn't work. I have this from imported Excel where in some cells are no values but I'm not able to remove them unless I used `LEN('') = 0` function.

Comment: I tried to set in where condition an empty string and in my case it works.

Comment: I would take a look at the [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/replace.php) for this.

Comment: @Galma88: it does not work as expected (from OP). It does not replace the empty string with 0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is nothing to replace in an empty string. [`REPLACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) replaces a **sequence** of characters in a string with another set of characters.

You could use `NULLIF` to treat it as `NULL` + `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL`):

```
declare @value varchar(10);
set @value = '';
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(@value,''), '0')
```

This returns `'0'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CASE for this.

```
(CASE WHEN *YOURTHING* = '' THEN '0' ELSE *YOURTHING* END) 
AS *YOURTHING*
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work. There are two proper behaviors here - first one is to return back empty string (what it does already), second one is to return infinite string full of zeroes.

Comment: He doesn't want to return an empty string from an already empty string. He wants to replace it with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! > Check multiple scenarios like '', remove spaces, Null, string/numeric result

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(mob, 0))) = '' THEN '0' ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(mob, 0)))  END  MobileNo 
FROM table1 WHERE emp_no = '01111'
```